# Circular variable/parameter reference in a Variable XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a simple XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="form.xsl"?>
<x>
    <y>Hello</y>
</x>
```

and `form.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="topLevel">
        <xsl:variable name="inner" select="'Hi'" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$inner"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:value-of select="$topLevel" />
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using `JRE 1.8,` and when i transform the XML using `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, i get a circular reference error, on the `topLevel` variable.

```
Circular variable/parameter reference in '[variable(topLevel)]
```

I found out that there is already an issue related to this logged at: [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2430), but am not sure if this has been fixed.

There are various workarounds provided but no solutions provided.

**Note**: I have not included any third party jars and am using the default Transformer implementation.

Comment: I don't see anything circular in your code and since [it works without any problems in Xalan 2.7.1](http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKvW) it's clearly unrelated to the link in your post.

Comment: The browser transforms it correctly. But When i do it via Java i get this error. How do you say that it works correctly in xalan 2.7.1?

Comment: Click the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah i saw, it . So you mean to say the transformation on the link occurs on the server side? I don't think so, since mine fails :(

Comment: Yes, it does. I wouldn't be able to see it otherwise (I don't have those engines installed on my computer).

Comment: Sure you're applying exactly this stylesheet to exactly the input XML you show?

Comment: Try using Apache Xalan instead of the version in the JDK. It's much better maintained. (Or move to Saxon...)

Comment: @MathiasMüller - Yeah, am sure.

Comment: @MichaelKay - I guess its a problem with the JDK implementation, will try out SAXON.

Comment: Works perfectly with the saxon implementation. Wonder why the default implementation fails.

Comment: I'm just looking through questions without an answer. This seems to be solved... Please create an answer yourself and mark it as accepted. Otherwise this question will remain on the "questions without an answer" list for ever, thx!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to definition of a variable within a (global) variable.

If you move this line
<xsl:variable name="inner" select="'Hi'" />

outside of the definition 'topLevel' then your code might work.

This kind thing is fine with Xalan 2.7.0 but triggers the error message in 2.7.1/2

I am writing this because I hit the same problem today, and this answer was first in google even though it is 7 years old.

I cannot tell you why this change in Xalan behaviour has been introduced, only that I observed the same thing and this is the workaround I found

Comment: *״The problem is due to definition of a variable within a (global) variable."*  No, the problem is due to a bug in your chosen processor. There is nothing wrong with the code and it will work perfectly fine with any conforming processor. And I get no error message when running this on Xalan 2.7.2.

Comment: Thanks, a colleague had told me there was a bug with Xalan 2.7.1 but I still saw an error reported with  Xalan 2.7.2 so I assumed there was still no fix in Xalan 2.7.2.  For our work we have stayed on Xalan 2.7.0 due to this issue, (and other issues we found).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error after removing xalan (for security reason) and using the jdk internal implementation:

> com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl

So I added  Saxon-HE 12.4 to my classpath and it is also working nicely and supports security attributes as ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD.